# RestKit mapping result populated, but not setting Core Data entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am trying to do a multi-part POST to create a new user w/ an attached image.  The `RKMappingResult` shows that it mapped the response successfully, but for some reason it's not mapping to the `User` entity object correctly since all of those attributes are still `nil` after the mapping.

RKMappingResult:

```
(lldb) po mappingResult
<RKMappingResult: 0xc8d04a0, results={
    user = "<User: 0xc8d4360> (entity: User; id: 0xc676560 <x-coredata://68DA437E-D836-48F7-B4CE-CC08EC38B98F/User/p15> ; data: {\n    accessToken = c81453227a39e16e396218d3a1ef0d80;\n    actions = nil;\n    createdAt = \"2013-12-11 15:34:45 +0000\";\n  email = \"user@users.com\";\n    firstName = Some;\n    fullName = \"Some User\";\n    lastName = User;\n    timezone = nil;\n    updatedAt = \"2013-12-11 15:34:45 +0000\";\n    username = nil;\n    uuid = \"de565267-eaf9-4cbf-a63e-44dd7df405aa\";\n})";
}>
```

Core Data `User` Entity (after mapping):

```
(lldb) po newUser
<User: 0xc8ac300> (entity: User; id: 0xc8c5050 <x-coredata:///User/t1251A6D9-8FB8-4AF2-AFA4-ADB61F39397F2> ; data: {
    accessToken = nil;
    actions = nil;
    createdAt = nil;
    email = nil;
    firstName = nil;
    fullName = "(null) (null)";
    lastName = nil;
    timezone = nil;
    updatedAt = nil;
    username = nil;
    uuid = nil;
})
```

Code:

```
User *newUser = [User createNewUser];
NSDictionary *userParams = @{kJsonUser : params};

NSURLRequest *request = [[APIClient objectManager] multipartFormRequestWithObject:newUser method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:kEndPointCreateListUsers parameters:userParams constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    UIImage *image = [params objectForKey:kJsonImage];
    if (image) {
      [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
                                name:@"user_image"
                            fileName:@"user_image.jpeg"
                            mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }
}];
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[APIClient objectManager] managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request managedObjectContext:[APIClient mainThreadContext] success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    [self handleSignUpSuccessForUser:newUser];
    success([newUser uuid]);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self handleSignUpFailure];
    failure([error localizedDescription]);
}];
[[APIClient objectManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```

The one thing I've noticed is that the memory address for the `User` in the mapping results is different than the `newUser` object.  If I use a normal (non-multipart) request, then it maps just fine and sets the Core Data object.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- From the mapping result: `<User: 0xc8d4360>`
- From your debug log: `<User: 0xc8ac300>`

So you are comparing / logging different objects.

The way you're creating the POST request means that you should destroy the `newUser` after making the request and take the `User` object provided to you in the mapping request instead.

If you were using an `RKObjectManager` then it would update the `newUser` for you but you wouldn't have an option to add the image data into the POST. Currently `newUser` is only used to generate the `request` and is not available to the mapping of the response.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Is there a better way to create the request so that the `RKObjectManager` I'm using (stored in `[APIClient objectManager]`) will update the `newUser` instead of me having to delete it and use the mapping result?

Comment: I don't think so - just because you are sending image data. It the image wasn't being sent then yes.

Comment: Cool, well thanks for the help!  I no longer pass in an object and then I use `User *newUser = [mappingResult firstObject];` now to get the newly created user.